# admin pages not displaying except dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, error, frontend-error

I have version 1.9.3.1

I got the following message in my dashboard:

```
One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Product Attributes,
Product Prices, Catalog URL Rewrites, Product Flat Data, Category Flat
Data, Category Products, Catalog Search Index, Stock Status, Tag
Aggregation Data. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild
required indexes.
```

I also get an error when i click the index rebuild...

```
There has been an error processing your request Exception printing 
is disabled by default for security reasons.
```

i've cleared my cache each time too but no luck, i've also tried reindexing via SSH using the following command: php shell/indexer.php reindexall.

My server log files show these errors...

```
2017-02-08 06:48:29 Error   80.229.47.81    503 GET /index.php/ts_admin/system_account/index/key/b688c8f9a47868a372a381ebb065b8bb/ HTTP/1.0 http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    2.51 K  Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:29 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /errors/default/css/styles.css HTTP/1.0 http://example.com/index.php/ts_admin/system_account/index/key/b688c8f9a47868a372a381ebb065b8bb/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    449 Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:29 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /errors/default/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1 http://example.com/index.php/ts_admin/system_account/index/key/b688c8f9a47868a372a381ebb065b8bb/    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    11.0 K  nginx access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/ HTTP/1.0        Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    13.2 K  Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css HTTP/1.0  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    452 Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css HTTP/1.0  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    460 Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/menu.css HTTP/1.0   http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    459 Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css HTTP/1.0  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    460 Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/custom.css HTTP/1.0 http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    1000    Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/print.css HTTP/1.0  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    460 Apache access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css HTTP/1.1  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    5.85 K  nginx access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/reset.css HTTP/1.1  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    2.86 K  nginx access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/menu.css HTTP/1.1   http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    4.00 K  nginx access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css HTTP/1.1  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    87.4 K  nginx access
2017-02-08 06:48:33 Access  80.229.47.81    200 GET /skin/adminhtml/default/default/print.css HTTP/1.1  http://example.com/ts_admin/dashboard/index/key/ce7cfc51cc5db517fd53a5b2a650c576/   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36    1.46 K  nginx access
plesk.com Join Us on Facebook    Suggest an Idea
Show
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: take a look at error trace by error file in `var/error` or by enabling printing errors in `errors/local.xml`

Comment: Thank you, this worked, plus i had to create a directory called `/tmp`.